# How to change separator in oauth2-proxy for X-FORWARDED-GROUPS

Tags: geoserver, oauth2-proxy

I am trying to have `oauth2-proxy` forward the user's groups, using the `X-FORWARDED-GROUPS` header, to a `GeoServer` instance.
The problem is that if a user belongs to multiple groups, `oauth2-proxy` sends a header like this:

X-FORWARDED-GROUPS: group1,group2

`GeoServer` on the other hand [expects](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/usergrouprole/rolesource.html) groups to be separated by a semicolon. I haven't found a way to change either the `GeoServer` separator ([related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/460792/37568)), or what `oauth2-proxy` uses.

Is there a way to change the separator?